# I need a modal to persist after website refresh in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, state

I need to make my modal persist after website refresh. As soon as a user logs out it refreshes page and modal saying "sign-out successful" disappears. I want the modal to show up after sign-out and persist until the user clicks the close button. I tried to use-effect, but I was likely using it wrong as I am new to react.

```
"use client";
import "./signinbutton.css";
import { signIn, signOut, useSession } from "next-auth/react";
import Modal from "./Modal";
import React, { useState } from "react";

import { AiOutlineUserAdd } from "react-icons/ai";
import { IoMdLogOut } from "react-icons/io";

const SigninButton = ({ darkMode }) => {
  const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = useState(false);

  const { data: session } = useSession();
  console.log(session?.user);

  // Function to open the modal
  function logOut() {
    signOut().then(() => {
      setIsModalOpen(true);
    });
  }

  // Function to close the modal
  function closeModal() {
    setIsModalOpen(false);
  }

  if (session && session.user) {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={logOut} className="profile-button">
          <div className="logout-icon">
            <IoMdLogOut
              size={32}
              color={darkMode ? "#ef9726" : "#0099d8"}
            ></IoMdLogOut>
          </div>
        </button>
        <Modal show={isModalOpen} onClose={closeModal}>
          <h2>Successful Signout</h2>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <button onClick={() => signIn()} className="profile-button">
      <div className="user-icon">
        <AiOutlineUserAdd
          size={34}
          color={darkMode ? "#ef9726" : "#0099d8"}
        ></AiOutlineUserAdd>
      </div>
    </button>
  );
};

export default SigninButton;
```

```
import React from "react";
import "./modal.css"; // You can create a separate CSS file for modal styles if needed.

const Modal = ({ show, onClose, children }) => {
  if (!show) return null;

  return (
    <div className="modal-overlay">
      <div className="modal-content">
        {children}
        <button onClick={onClose}>Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Modal;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to make the modal persist even after the refresh, then you  can use localStorage to do that.

```
const KEY = 'SHOW_MODAL';

const Modal = () => {
  const value = localStorage.getItem(KEY);
  const parsedValue = value ? JSON.parse(value) : null;
  
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(parsedValue);

  onClose = () => {
     setShowModal(!showModal);
     localStorage.setItem(KEY, JSON.stringify(false));
  }

  onOpen = () => {
     setShowModal(!showModal);
     localStorage.setItem(KEY, JSON.stringify(true));
  }

  return (showModal ? 
     <div>
       <button onClick={onOpen}>Open</button>
       <button onClick={onClose}>Close</button>
     </div> : null)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your `useState` with custom hook like next (the code is in Typescript, but you can take JS version [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wK6uABWFVAS3WGRgGUYBDGYOAXjgB4AVAGgD4AKAa2AE8AXHHRRCyAOZs44wjEJUANgDUlGYMJYBKBhzgBvALAAoOGcQp0cANrjk%20SjWDTsMAJLJ7UR7QC6DOAAlYCoEGAA6LGAfYC5ZeSVVRXUtAG4TE3MgkLDI7ABRADNC4DCuLh16PSNTLPMkNHhFVCT1AMUIBCVKaCoJYHD%2091oAW14BNMy6swarZtbcKgJgABN2lrU6AH44AClyAHkAOXCwJewuec2dYWQMRUV02unCQrhLjeTF5ZWdGunpq4PF4Yh8FjhzqtJs86gBfODAZp0f4ArJAzwOai0OLIOQKFTXJ6o2FTMyw6TWPj8aTxfELXzQ0lwKDAGAYKDIGxMrJ2TFONjc8xcewAdwWmkq1UFgNZwL52NFC2hqKyHS6ih6UD6AyBo3G1L2hxOonEEle-GFwDF12VAPJTP8VFQFkaT1hqSAA)):

```
export const usePersistentState = <T,>(key: string, initialValue: T) => {
    const [innerState, setInnerState] = React.useState(initialValue);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        const lsValue = localStorage.getItem(key);
        const lsValueParsed = lsValue ? JSON.parse(lsValue) : null;
        if (lsValueParsed) {
            setInnerState(lsValueParsed);
        } else {
            setInnerState(initialValue);
        }
    }, [key, initialValue]);

    return [
        innerState,
        (newValue: T) => {
            setInnerState(newValue);
            localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(newValue));
        },
    ] as const;
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! I tried this and unfortunately  I did not work. I'm sorry I am very new to programming, but do you think there could be another reason the modal is disappearing instantly rather than the site refresh. The refresh was my assumption.